# how to list the top ten director_name that has the highest average of director_facebook_likes

Tags: python, pandas

i use

```
count = df['director_name']
count.head(10)
```

to find the top directors but I do not know how to implement finding the top ten directors with the most director_facebook_likes how can I do that
any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that there are two columns in your dataframe

1. `director_name`
2. `director_facebook_likes`

if you want to get the top 10 directors based on Facebook likes count

this would be the option

```
df.nlargest(10, 'director_facebook_likes')
```

to know more about `nlargest` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html